# Differentiate State Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented a multiple edit functionality in a react grid! Similar to the one in the link below!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7ppb.gif

How do I differentiate one state value from the other! For example I am looking to edit a name! I have a [name, setName] = useState(). I set the value of name via a onChange handler. If I edit name in row 1, it automatically gets updated in row 2 as well. How do I differentiate the edited name from row 1 to row 2 and only capture the edited value?

Comment: You can’t if you only have a single state. You need a state-per-row, or a way to distinguish which row is being worked on if only a single row can be operated on at a time.

Comment: You can allow one edit at a time. That is one thing that I can think as of now.

Comment: My suggestion is splitting each row out into their own component, then having a single name state would work and only update the specific row you are wanting to update